# Finding element in jquery ajax html answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The following code:

```
        ajax_obj = $.ajax(
        {
        data: data,
        success: function(answer)
        {
            console.log(answer);
            console.log($('#table_conferences_tbody', answer).html());
            console.log($(answer).find('tbody').html());
            console.log($(answer).find('tr').length);
        }
    });
```

Console Result:

```
<div><tbody id="table_conferences_tbody"><tr id="conf26" class="darkrow"><td><span class="expand">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="cm_aln">20.03.26</td><td class="no_border">13:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>14:00</td><td>TEst</td><td>Test</td><td>Dr. Fariss Chegrani</td></tr><tr id="conf25" class="lightrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">20.02.26</td><td class="no_border">12:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>13:00</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td> Petra Haubrich</td></tr><tr id="conf27" class="darkrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">20.03.20</td><td class="no_border">12:11</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>13:11</td><td>Test</td><td>TEst</td><td>Dr. Ariane Hähn</td></tr><tr id="conf24" class="lightrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">30.11.12</td><td class="no_border">15:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>17:00</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td> Petra Haubrich</td></tr></tbody></div>
undefined
undefined
0
```

I don't understand why I can't find any elements within the answer. It works with others answers, so I'm really stuck here. I validated the html answer, it seems correct. What did I do wrong? Thank you very much...

Comment: Did you forget ajax url?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, there is no `<table>`, so everything *table related* is stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)
>
> **Usage context**:
>
> Permitted parent elements:
>
> Within the **required**
>   parent `<table>` element, the `<tbody>` element can be added after a
>   `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, `<thead>` and a `<tfoot>` element.

---

If possible, try adding `<table>` element to wrap `<tbody>` element within html. See [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

```js
// added `<table>` element as parent of `<tbody>` element
var html = '<div><table><tbody id="table_conferences_tbody"><tr id="conf26" class="darkrow"><td><span class="expand">&nbsp;</span></td><td class="cm_aln">20.03.26</td><td class="no_border">13:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>14:00</td><td>TEst</td><td>Test</td><td>Dr. Fariss Chegrani</td></tr><tr id="conf25" class="lightrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">20.02.26</td><td class="no_border">12:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>13:00</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td> Petra Haubrich</td></tr><tr id="conf27" class="darkrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">20.03.20</td><td class="no_border">12:11</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>13:11</td><td>Test</td><td>TEst</td><td>Dr. Ariane Hähn</td></tr><tr id="conf24" class="lightrow"><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="cm_aln">30.11.12</td><td class="no_border">15:00</td><td class="cm_aln no_border">&minus;</td><td>17:00</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td> Petra Haubrich</td></tr></tbody></table></div>';
var answer = $(html);
console.log(answer);
console.log($('#table_conferences_tbody', answer).html());
console.log(answer.find('tbody').html()); // removed second call to `jQuery()` around `answer`
console.log(answer.find('tr').length);

var withTable = "<div><table><tbody><tr>b</tr></tbody></table></div>";
var withoutTable = "<div><tbody><tr>a</tr></tbody></div>";    
console.log($(withTable), $(withTable).find("tbody")
           , $(withoutTable),  $(withoutTable).find("tbody"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works fine! Thank you very much! Can you help me to understand the problem? I thought JQuery does not validate the html, so why recognizes it the missing table tag?