# select class of raw html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
   myhtml = '<tr><td>1</td><td>Orange</td><td>1799.00 x <span>1</span></td><td>0.00</td><td>1799.00</td></tr><tr class="shippingRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Shipping</td><td>2.00</td></tr><tr class="totalRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>1811.00</strong></td></tr>'
   console.log($(myhtml).find('.shippingRow td').length);
});
```

I got zero instead of one, which part I missed out? I want to remove the class name or do some styling to myhtml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.shippingRow` tr is not nested inside any other element in your HTML string. This means that it is one of the elements in the jQuery object that it returns. (i.e., since you have 3 tr's, `$(myhtml).length` will return 3).

Since [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) only searches *descendants* of the elements in the jQuery object, it doesn't find any element with the class shippingRow.

One method is to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$(myhtml).filter(".shippingRow").find("td").length
```

Comment: filter is slower than find right? maybe i should wrap the tags properly.

Comment: @AliceXu I would say that in this scenario the performance difference is probably negligible. It's usually hard to gauge performance anyway since different browsers perform differently. The operations are only being called on a small set of elements. It's possible that creating the element to wrap it properly might even offset any potential performance gain.

Comment: I just found that I can't manipulate it. `$(myhtml).filter(".shippingRow").find("td").attr('style','padding:10px');` <-- doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `<table><tbody>` at beginning of `myhtml` , `</tbody></table>` at close of `myhtml` , see [Finding element in jquery ajax html answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016436/finding-element-in-jquery-ajax-html-answer/)

```js
myhtml = '<table><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Orange</td><td>1799.00 x <span>1</span></td><td>0.00</td><td>1799.00</td></tr><tr class="shippingRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Shipping</td><td>2.00</td></tr><tr class="totalRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>1811.00</strong></td></tr></tbody></table>';

console.log($(myhtml).find('.shippingRow td').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Element will be a part of DOM only if its appended only in document.

Your example is only a string, you need to put that string into document to be a valid DOM.

You can do it like this:

```
var myhtml='<tr><td>1</td><td>Orange</td><td>1799.00 x <span>1</span></td><td>0.00</td><td>1799.00</td></tr><tr class="shippingRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Shipping</td><td>2.00</td></tr><tr class="totalRow"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><strong>Total</strong></td><td><strong>1811.00</strong></td></tr>';
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var span= document.createElement("span");
$(span).append(myhtml);
fragment.appendChild(span);
console.log($(span).find('.shippingRow td').length);
```

I used document fragment so that your html will not be a part of the DOM tree but can still be accessible via javascript. Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

> DocumentFragments are DOM Nodes. They are never part of the main DOM
>   tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append
>   elements to the document fragment and then append the document
>   fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is
>   replaced by all its children.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/0oxdqdot/